# representation of integral of the indicator function

Tags: integration

I'm trying to see whether
$$ f(y) =\int_0^1 I\{ f(u)\leq y \}\,du $$
where $f$ is measurable. and $I$ is the indicator function. It should be true but I can't see why.

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take for $f$ the constant function equal to $1$.

Then $\{ u \in [0,1] ; f(u)\leq 1/2 \} = \emptyset$ and $I\{ f(u)\leq 1/2 \} = 0$ for $u \in [0,1]$. However
$$1 = f(1/2) \neq \int_0^1 I\{ f(u)\leq y \}\,du = 0$$